# Topological spaces and common internal points.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a topological spaces and let $A,B$ be open sets. Suppose that $$A\subseteq \text{Int}(B).$$

> Is it true or false that $$\text{Int}(A)\cap\text{Int}(B)\ne\emptyset.$$ If it is not true in general, are there conditions for it to be true? Could you give me some examples?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected

Comment: It's false. For example, $A=\varnothing$. It is true only if $\operatorname{Int}(A)\neq\varnothing$. (Since $A$ is open, $\operatorname{Int}(A)=A$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That assertion is true if and only if $\mathring A\neq\emptyset$. In fact, if $\mathring A=\emptyset$, then it is trivial that $\mathring A\cap\mathring B=\emptyset$. And if $\mathring A\neq\emptyset$, then, since $\mathring A$ is an open subset of $B$, $\mathring A\subset\mathring B$.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly we have $Int(A)\subseteq Int(B)$ (since $Int(Z)\subseteq Z$ for all $Z$ and $A\subseteq Int(B)$). But this does *not* mean that $Int(A)\cap Int(B)\not=\emptyset$.

*(It may help to think more generally. Suppose $U\subseteq V$. Why can't you conclude that $U\cap V\not=\emptyset$?)*

> What happens if $Int(A)=\emptyset$?

From this you can get an easy characterization of when your statement is true:

> You're assuming that $A$ is *open*. What can you say about an open set with empty interior?